# Neo4J Enterprise slower than Community?

Tags: neo4j, database-performance, neo4j-apoc

I've been doing some testing between Neo4J Community 3.3.3, Enterprise 3.3.9 and Enterprise 3.5.17.

To my surprise, the newer the version, the longer it took for requests to process.

And yes, I checked that all the indexes (both internal and APOC ones on all the parameters I use for the search) were in place when I transferred the DB. And for the version 3.5 I even updated the lucene indexes to the native ones, as suggested.

Here are my results for the following queries that produce about 12000 results each (about 500000 db hits)

```
PROFILE MATCH (u:User{uid:'16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff'}), 
(u)<-[:BY]-(ctx:Context) 
WITH COLLECT (DISTINCT ctx.uid) as contexts 
WITH 'context:('+apoc.text.join(contexts,' ')+')' AS query 
CALL apoc.index.relationships('BY',query) 
YIELD start, rel 
WHERE 'Statement' IN LABELS(start) 
RETURN DISTINCT start, rel;
```

3.3.3 community: 3500 ms (1000 ms consecutive loads)

3.3.9 enterprise: 1850 ms (1350 ms)

3.5.17 enterprise: 3500 ms (1500 ms)

and then for this kind of query:

```
PROFILE MATCH (u:User{uid:'16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff'}), 
(u)<-[rel:BY]-(s:Statement) 
RETURN distinct s, rel;
```

3.3.3 community: 1500 ms (1000 ms consecutive loads)

3.3.9 enterprise: 3100 ms (1300 ms)

3.5.17 enterprise: 4000 ms (2800 ms)

I also noticed that the native relationship indexes are much slower than the apoc ones.

For example for the two queries:

APOC:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('IN','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') 
YIELD start,end RETURN DISTINCT start, end;
```

vs the new native Neo4J indexes:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships('IN','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') YIELD relationship WITH DISTINCT relationship, startNode(relationship) AS start, endNode(relationship) AS end RETURN start, end;
```

The native relationship index is twice(!) slower.

Why is enterprise slower than the community version?

And how can the speed be improved?

Comment: For these kinds of questions, it would help to know your hardware configuration, and how you've configured your heap and pagecache memory, as well as the versions of APOC tested. Also if you have a means to download or recreate the graph for testing, that would help.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I left in both versions the heap and pagecache memory as default. The versions of APOC were the most up to date in relation to each version. The database is private, so I could not share it. The configuration was Mac OS X 10.15.4 Catalina and another separate Ubuntu box

Comment: When defaults are used, the values are dynamically chosen. Please check your debug logs to determine what heap and pagecache are being used, as well as the total memory available.

Comment: Can you share your query plans? And it would be good if you used the same system with the same JVM and configuration to compare.

Comment: How did you create the indexes?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `DISTINCT` when you `CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships` if you are just looking at the returned entities themselves, because that procedure always return distinct entities. If you want distinct results over the combination of relationship entity, start- and end-node, then I guess you need that, unless you can model your way out of it.

I created a dataset with roughly one million relationships, and got these results (repeated query execution several times, reporting lowest result):

First, straight-line APOC: `profile call apoc.index.relationships("R", "name:*") yield rel,weight return count(rel)` took 6101 ms.

Straight-line schema FTS: `profile call db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships("rels_r", "*") yield relationship return count(relationship)` took 1611 ms.

Schema FTS with useless distinct: `profile call db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships("rels_r", "*") yield relationship as r with distinct r return count(r)` took 2569 ms.

Schema FTS with resolving the relationship start node: `profile call db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships("rels_r", "*") yield relationship as r with startNode(r) as s return count(s)` took 1957 ms. (Adding in the end node as well made it slightly slower still, but I'll skip it here)

Schema FTS with both distinct and start node: `profile call db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships("rels_r", "*") yield relationship as r with distinct r, startNode(r) as s return count(s)` took 3040 ms.

Same as above, but with end node as well: `profile call db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships("rels_r", "*") yield relationship as r with distinct r, startNode(r) as s, endNode(r) as e return count(s)` took 3580 ms.

Same as above, but with APOC: `profile call apoc.index.relationships("R", "name:*") yield rel,weight with distinct rel, startNode(rel) as s, endNode(rel) as e return count(s)` took 7137 ms.

This is on Neo4j 3.5.17, same as what you report in your post. The queries above scans all the contents of the indexes, but the results are repeatable when I use very selective queries too.

Sorry this is a "works for me" kind of answer wrt. the full text indexes, but in the absence of a better way to try to recreate the problem this is what I got.